# Two circles intersecting, common tangent

Tags: geometry, circles, tangent-line, geometric-transformation, power-of-the-point

Two circles intersecting in $A$ and $B$. They have a common tangent, with point $P$ on circle one and point $Q$ on circle two. Prove that the line through $A$ and $B$ cuts the line $PQ$ by half.

[image]

Comment: Let the intersection of AB and PQ be R. Since AB is the radical axis and hence tangents from R to the two circles are of equal length and hence RP = RQ

Answer (score 4):

Let $R$ be the intersection of the line $PQ$ and the line $AB$. Then by the [Tangent-Secant Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent-secant_theorem)
$$|PR|^2=|RA|\cdot|RB|=|RQ|^2.$$

Answer (score 2):

Similarly in spirit to Robert Z's answer, invert about the intersection point with inversion circle passing through $P$. Then, the *entire diagram* looks the same under inversion, hence the distance $QR$ is the inversion radius, which is $PR$.

Answer (score 1):

Let the point of intersection of $PQ$ and $BA$ (produced) be $X$.
Now, using tangent secant theorem,
$$XP^2 = XA \cdot XB.       \tag{1}$$

Similarly, 
$$XQ^2 = XA \cdot XB.      \tag{2}$$

Using (1) and (2),
$$XP^2 = XQ^2 \Longrightarrow XP = XQ.$$

Therefore the line through $A$ and $B$ cuts the line $PQ$ by half.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)